# How to receive json in Dancer?

Tags: perl, dancer

I am very new to Perl framework Dancer. As of now I have a get http listener working. I have an Angular framework trying to post a json string to Dancer. How can I retreive the json and perhaps assign it to a scalar variable ($json).

```
get '/games' => sub {
    header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*';
    &loadgames();
    return $games;
};

post '/newgame' => sub {
    header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*';
    #what should i put here to retrieve the json string
    #I plan to pass the json string to a sub to convert to XML
};
```

I am not sure If I chose Dancer as backend framework that will get and post data.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

If your HTTP request has a JSON body (`Content-type: application/json`) rather than being an HTML form post, then you probably want something like this:

```
post '/url-path' => {
    my $post = from_json( request->body );
    # do something with the POSTed data structure
    # which would typically be a hashref (or an arrayref)
    # e.g.: schema->resultset('Widget')->create($post);
}
```

The `from_json` routine is one of the [DSL Keywords](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual.pod#DSL-KEYWORDS) provided by Dancer.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely used the `from_json`

Answer (score 0):

Dancer provides the [`params`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Request#params-source) keyword for accessing route, body, and query parameters. You want a body parameter. Exactly *which* body parameter you want will depend on the name of the field you posted it to the route with (look at your form or your ajax request).

```
my $json_string = params('body')->{$field_name}
```

You can also use [`param`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#param), if you don't have any conflicting parameter names in the route or query parameters.

Once you have the json, remember it's just a string at the moment. You might want to read it into a perl data structure: Dancer provides [`from_json`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#from_json-structure-options) for this purpose.

As an aside: I notice in your get route, you call a function `loadgames` in void context, and then return a variable you haven't declared (or perhaps you have set it as a global - but do you need it to be a global?). I recommend beginning each perl file with `use strict;` to pick up issues like this. I suspect you probably just want to use the return value of `loadgames` as your return value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the side suggestion!